# Referring to range of cells through range(cells(x,y), cells(x+a,y+b))

Tags: excel, vba

I want to automate moving blocks of cells, and am encountering issues when attempting to use `range(cells(x,y), cells(x+a, y+b)) [a, b, x, y are integer variables]`. Essentially, I would like to replicate `offset("A1",x-1,y-1,a,b)` from plain Excel. The problem is that VBA will look up the value of `cells(x,y)` instead of using it simply as a position reference.

For example, say `x=1, y=1, a=3, b=2 and A1 [r1, c1`] in the worksheet is "Potato" and `D5 [r5, c4]` is "Apple". VBA will reduce.

```
    range(cells(x,y), cells(x+a, y+b))
```

to

```
    range("Potato","Apple")
```

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: no it won't, it creates the range, using your numbers, A1:D5.  Why do you think it the other way?

Comment: What issue are you getting (possibly an error code?) when you try to move your block of cells?  If X, Y, A, & B, are all defined appropriately, you shouldn't run into issues.  This is a pretty standard approach, e.g., range(cells(i,1),cells(i+10,LR)) where LR is last row and i is the coded variable.

Comment: it would if you used `cells(x,y).value` but since you're omitting that it should default to return the range. If you want to specify, which may be good practice, use `cells(x,y).address`

Comment: I think I found the issue. It looks like it arises from a part I removed out of simplification.
I'm referring to a different sheet (MySheet="Sheet1") and Sheets(MySheet).range(cells(x,y), cells(x+a, y+b)) was causing errors when another sheet was active. It seems I have to have range(Sheets(MySheet).cells(x,y), Sheets(MySheet).cells(x+a, y+b)) instead.
Thanks everyone, though!